# Selenium checkbox data driven - Checkbox has only target but no value

Tags: selenium, checkbox

Im having difficulties parameterizing (data driven) checkboxes using Selenium IDE. When I record selecting a checkbox using Selenium i get the following action:

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>id=_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_UseCaseBesturing__ctl1_dgOndersteundeChannels__ctl2_chkbxChannel</td>
<td></td>
```

In order to parameterize this action and pointing to my test data (XML) file I need a value which I can set as a variable. But in this action there is no value, only a target which is the ID.

Any ideas how to parameterize this action or how to check the checkbox using a value instead of using only the target (ID)?

P.S. Text fields work fine by putting "*${Parametername}*" in value field in Selenium for an action. The Parametername will then be my column name in my test data file.

Html code of the checkboxes:

```
<table class="detailgrid" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_UseCaseBesturing__ctl1_dgOndersteundeChannels" style="border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="width:20px;">
                            <span disabled="disabled"><input id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_UseCaseBesturing__ctl1_dgOndersteundeChannels__ctl2_chkbxChannel" type="checkbox" name="_ctl0:MainContentPlaceHolder:UseCaseBesturing:_ctl1:dgOndersteundeChannels:_ctl2:chkbxChannel" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"></span>
                        </td><td>
                            <span id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_UseCaseBesturing__ctl1_dgOndersteundeChannels__ctl2_lblChannelNaam">POS</span>
                        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="width:20px;">
                            <input id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_UseCaseBesturing__ctl1_dgOndersteundeChannels__ctl3_chkbxChannel" type="checkbox" name="_ctl0:MainContentPlaceHolder:UseCaseBesturing:_ctl1:dgOndersteundeChannels:_ctl3:chkbxChannel">
                        </td><td>
                            <span id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_UseCaseBesturing__ctl1_dgOndersteundeChannels__ctl3_lblChannelNaam">eCommerce</span>
                        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
                            <br>
                            <span type="checkbox"><input id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_UseCaseBesturing__ctl1_dgOndersteundeChannels__ctl4_chkalles1" type="checkbox" name="_ctl0:MainContentPlaceHolder:UseCaseBesturing:_ctl1:dgOndersteundeChannels:_ctl4:chkalles1" onclick="CheckAll('chkbxChannel', this.checked);"></span>
                        </td><td>
                            <br>
                            Alles Aan
                        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Consider using XPath.

Comment: I tried xpath=//td/span[text()='POS'] but it doesnt work. It doesnt give any error in Selenium, but it just dont check any of the checkboxes.

Comment: I put the whole html code of the checkbox area, maybe this helps getting some ideas how to get this work.

There are 3 possible checkboxes (POS, eCommerce, Alles aan). I want to make this variable in selenium so i can use my test data to define which checkbox should be checked.

Comment: Post your code. Remember, `span` is not a checkbox, regardless of what it looks like in the browser. Have you tried using `click()`. What else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Still use a click but change how you find the target by using xpath.

It would look something like this:

Target:

```
xpath=//td/span[text()='POS']
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After going through the question, I tried using parameter for Target in the test step( as it was not possible to parameterize Action(Command) after various attempts) in Selenium IDE.

To select a checkbox the `Xpath` should point to the input tag and can be checked using `click` command.

IMO, as per the HTML, the correct `Xpath` for checking the checkbox corresponding to `eCommerce` should be :

`//span[text()='eCommerce']/ancestor::td/preceding-sibling::td/input`